# Use Magento or develop my own script?

Tags: php, websites

I am a web developer, and I've recently gotten into selling stuff online, and now I am ready to take my products and make an e-commerce site. Heres the thing, I can code my own e-commerce website but I think it will be time-consuming, yet if it's built right I would be able to customize it to whichever way I like it and maybe sell the script itself. So should I go ahead or just stick with Magento?

Answer (score 2):

Use Magento (or any other existing framework).

Your time and effort is better spent customising Magento to your needs rather than starting from scratch. Magento is very customisable out of the box already (and if it doesn't do what you need your efforts are better spent changing Magento than to built everything yourself).

Magento is built by a huge team of core developers aided by a wider community - see [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2) - so a lot of use cases, features, etc are already there ready for you to use. It also comes with a wide ecosystem of extra functionality and features provided through extensions which you would also miss out on building on your own.

Comment: magento acts pathetic sometimes as am facing an issue intsalling it on ubuntu on a apache server but its stucks everytime at certain points and the most pathetic out of that is it even stuck due to browser cache

Answer (score 1):

In short, i suggest to **go with the recent Magento 1.9.3.x or 2.x open source platforms**, as its a *proven e-commerce platform, which is scalable, well-tested, well-documented and has a great community of support* (specifically on Magento Stack Exchange). It can be *integrated easily with any other widely used ERPs, CRMs* in the market.

Using Magento's built-in features you can easily set up your e-commerce store (*adding your catalog, adding shipping carriers, adding payment gateway providers, adding CMS pages about your store, privacy policy etc*). As a major highlight, in **[Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/)** you can find extensions (add-ons / modules) for any kind of features that you need, as well as you can find different set of themes for your needs.

If you want to learn Magento 1.x or 2.x, i agree there is a steep learning curve for any beginner but its worth the time and effort.

On the other hand, I see **its a bad idea to write your own script for your e-commerce store**, because of the following concerns

1. You need to test your code in different use cases (scenarios), as e-commerce is a serious business, store owner cannot afford any kind of errors in their platform. Here am talking about not just the features, am emphasizing a lot about **web security**.
2. Secondly though you are confident that you can monetize your e-commerce script, **why should others prefer your solution than the proven e-commerce solution like Magento** or any other open-source platforms ?

Go with Magento you will be happy making this decision. If you find its hard to customize leave the job to Magento certified developers or partnered agencies (near by to your location). Though i highlighted the benefits of moving to magento, make the decision based on your budget, schedule and effort required.